# Intersection of two pytorch tensors without loops; ideally multidimensional

Tags: python, pytorch, mesh

**TL; DR:**

I have two pytorch tensors:

```
t_1 = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
t_2 = torch.Tensor([1, 5, 7])
```

The desired output is supposed to contain the indices where the elements of `t_2` appear in `t_1`, i.e.:

```
output = torch.Tensor([0, 4, 6])
```

What is critical is that all operations are performed on the GPU, without loops but rather just pytorch operations. The operation itself will be used for very large tensors.

**Long version:**

The first tensor contains the faces of a triangle mesh. Each face is characterised by 3 indices to individual vertices. There exist F faces, hence the dimensions of the tensor are `Fx3`. It contains integers only.

The second tensor has a variable amount of potential faces. Each potential face is also characterised by 3 indices to individual vertices. However, these could be in a different order than in the first tensor. The number of faces changes from iteration to iteration, but is not equal to F, hence `Nx3` where `N!=F`. It contains integers only.

I want to check, what the index of each potential face of the second array is in the first array. This will help me use pre-computed values, that I have already computed for `t_1`.

My current solution relies on calculating a unique value for each triplet in the tensors, thus flattening out the two-dimensional array and arriving at a one-dimensional tensor. Then I can compare these, however, I have not been able to do so efficiently. Furthermore, I have to compute each of the 6 possible combinations of the three indices in each face.

Answer (score 0):

If t_2 and t_1 are already sorted like in the example you can use torch.searchsorted.

```
torch.searchsorted(t_1, t_2)
```

Comment: they are not, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how efficient this solution is, but it might help:

```
eq_matrix = torch.eq(t_1[:, None], t_2)
output = torch.nonzero(eq_matrix)[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `t_1` and `t_2` are both 1-d tensor and already sorted, you can use `torch.searchsorted` to quickly find the intersection.

```py
import torch


def intersection(t_1: torch.Tensor, t_2: torch.Tensor):
    if t_2.shape[0] > t_1.shape[0]:
        t_1, t_2 = t_2, t_1

    idx = torch.searchsorted(t_1[:-1], t_2)
    mask = (t_1[idx] == t_2)
    res = t_2[mask]

    return res


t_1 = torch.Tensor([1, 5, 10])
t_2 = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
print(intersection(t_1, t_2))
```

Output:

```
tensor([1., 5.])
```